# oracle db : change specified string in column values

Tags: regex, string, oracle, substring

I have to change values in following 'action' column:

```
        action                                                  target
provisionning,deletion,deprecation,consultation                 target1
restrict,lock,unlock,consultation,deletion                      target2
```

i've to replace the 'consultation' in this column with 'display' value on all lines.

i've no solution, can somebody help me please ?

thnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this for oracle..

```
update table_name set action=replace(action,'consultation','display');
```